# Excel formula to identify and group figures

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have two columns A and B

In column A, I have figures in some currency say US Dollars. In column B, I have account codes to which the figures should be grouped.

```
A          B
USd       Codes
2,500     100
5,000     110 
3,000     110 
4,000     100
6,000     120
```

How can I write a formula to group the figures which belongs to each of code 100, 110 and 120 to a separate column say column C?

In C the group total for code 100 should be `2,500 + 4,000 = 6,500`, for code 110 it should be `5,000 + 3,000 = 8,000`, etc.

Comment: Look into `sumif`

Comment: You may also want to consider using a Pivot Table to group and summarize this data. It would depend upon your needs.

Answer (score 0):

As Raystafarian says, this can be done quite simply by using [`SUMIF`](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/SUMIF-function-5fd078db-e5f8-4726-b08f-74fd0064e7fe?ui=en-US&rs=en-NZ&ad=NZ). The syntax for `SUMIF` is quite simple, in your case a sample formula could look like this:

```
=SUMIF(B2:B6,100,A2:A6)
```

As you can see, it takes three arguments:

- The first is the range which you want to evaluate against some criteria
- The second is the criteria you want to compare the values in the first argument against
- The third is the range which will be summed if the criteria in the second argument is fulfilled in the range specified in the first argument.

The third argument is optional, if you omit it the range entered as the first argument is also the one which will be summed. For more details, you should look into the link I gave earlier in the answer or maybe just try to google "sumif".

You should also note that in some locales a semi-colon (`;`) is used to separate arguments instead of the comma (`,`) I used in the sample formula.

Given all this, I am sure you can figure out how to create a formula for your other two codes on your own. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to summarize this information is with a [Pivot Table](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/Quick-start-Create-a-PivotTable-report-0c220f35-e478-49aa-beaf-24018b7f0f64). A Pivot Table is used to group and summarize data. In this example I grouped by the Code and then set the value to the USD field, and made sure to tally by sum.

[image: Example solution using Pivot Table]